# how to get list of instance type using aws java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

how to get aws predefined instance Type(flavors) by using java sdk.by which method call I get the list of available flavors

Answer (score 1):

The SDK provides an enum of available types:

com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.InstanceType

List (Version 1.8.8 of the SDK):

```
T1Micro("t1.micro"),
M1Small("m1.small"),
M1Medium("m1.medium"),
M1Large("m1.large"),
M1Xlarge("m1.xlarge"),
M3Medium("m3.medium"),
M3Large("m3.large"),
M3Xlarge("m3.xlarge"),
M32xlarge("m3.2xlarge"),
T2Micro("t2.micro"),
T2Small("t2.small"),
T2Medium("t2.medium"),
M2Xlarge("m2.xlarge"),
M22xlarge("m2.2xlarge"),
M24xlarge("m2.4xlarge"),
Cr18xlarge("cr1.8xlarge"),
I2Xlarge("i2.xlarge"),
I22xlarge("i2.2xlarge"),
I24xlarge("i2.4xlarge"),
I28xlarge("i2.8xlarge"),
Hi14xlarge("hi1.4xlarge"),
Hs18xlarge("hs1.8xlarge"),
C1Medium("c1.medium"),
C1Xlarge("c1.xlarge"),
C3Large("c3.large"),
C3Xlarge("c3.xlarge"),
C32xlarge("c3.2xlarge"),
C34xlarge("c3.4xlarge"),
C38xlarge("c3.8xlarge"),
Cc14xlarge("cc1.4xlarge"),
Cc28xlarge("cc2.8xlarge"),
G22xlarge("g2.2xlarge"),
Cg14xlarge("cg1.4xlarge"),
R3Large("r3.large"),
R3Xlarge("r3.xlarge"),
R32xlarge("r3.2xlarge"),
R34xlarge("r3.4xlarge"),
R38xlarge("r3.8xlarge");
```

Comment: By which method I get list of Instances(flavors),I am using 1.7.2 sdk

Comment: Why can't you use the same enum as above? The values may be different, because Amazon have added new instance types since they released 1.7.2.